Is there an easy way to merge object arrays using javascript ellipsis or similar?


let arr = [
  {id: 1, data: {foo: "bar 1"}},
  {id: 2, data: {foo: "bar 2"}}
];

//In case the ID does not exist just add as a new element on the array
arr = [...arr, {id: 3, data: {foo: "bar 3"}}]
console.log(arr);

//In case the ID exists, replace the data object with the new array provided
arr = [...arr, {id: 2, data: {foo: "new data object"}}]
console.log(arr);

//Expected output:
[
  {id: 1, data: {foo: "bar 1"}},
  {id: 2, data: {foo: "new data object"}},
  {id: 3, data: {foo: "bar 3"}}
]



As you can see in the example bellow, you can only add a new element even thought the ID is the same.
Is there a way to give an object that replaces the object with the same ID in case that it exists, but adds it as a new element to the array if the ID is not found?
I know that I can use the arr.find(i => i.id == newObject.id) to check if that row exists or not and add as a new one or replace depending on the result, but I would like to know if there is a one line solution for this

... here is called the spread syntax. And no, it doesn't do magic. It just "spreads" some data into another container. That's it. Doesn't look up, or merge, or mutate the data it spreads.

Arrays don't care if the elements inside them are unique or not. Perhaps you could use an Object with the ids as keys; then it would either add the new Object or overwrite it if the key already exists.

"I would like to know if there is a one line solution for this" also - yes there is. 1. define a function. 2. use your function which will now take up one line. 3. think if you even need to make the 2-3 line function even shorter. Or a whole alternative path: don't use arrays if you seem to need a dictionary. Neither of these rely on spread syntax.

"I would like to know if there is a one line solution for this" Depends on how much you are willing to write into one line ... Problems like this oftentimes are resolved using   reduce and/or Maps

If you are looking for one line solution using array filter and concat :


let arr = [
  { id: 1, data: { foo: "bar 1" } },
  { id: 2, data: { foo: "bar 2" } }
];


let newObj = { id: 2, data: { foo: "new data object" } };
arr = arr.filter((obj) => obj.id !== newObj.id).concat(newObj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));

newObj = { id: 3, data: { foo: "bar 3" } };

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.filter((obj) => obj.id !== newObj.id).concat(newObj)));



Else go for one line solution like below using Spread operator :


let arr = [
  { id: 1, data: { foo: "bar 1" } },
  { id: 2, data: { foo: "bar 2" } }
];


let newObj = { id: 2, data: { foo: "new data object" } };
arr = [...arr.filter(obj => obj.id !== newObj.id), newObj];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));


newObj = { id: 3, data: { foo: "bar 3" } };
arr = [...arr.filter(obj => obj.id !== newObj.id), newObj];

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));




Yes, good catch using the combination of array filter + merge

This is not a one-liner, but reasonably short and easy to read/maintain:


let arr = [
  {id: 1, data: {foo: "bar 1"}},
  {id: 2, data: {foo: "bar 2"}}
];

const updArr=[
  {id: 3, data: {foo: "bar 3"}}, 
  {id: 2, data: {foo: "new data object"}}];

updArr.forEach(u=>{
 let i=arr.findIndex(a=>a.id==u.id);
 if (i>=0) arr[i]=u;
 else arr.push(u)
});

console.log(arr);




yes, this works, it is what I was doing but I was looking for a more direct way to achieve it. Thanks anyway
